# Google Play Games v2 increment immediate not working

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm trying to integrate Google Play Games Services to my android game. I'm trying to increment immediate an incremental achievement. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/AchievementsClient#public-abstract-taskboolean-incrementimmediate-string-id,-int-numsteps), the `Task` returns a boolean, telling wether the achievement has been unlocked or not.

My problem is that the boolean with the result is always false, event when the achievement has been already unlocked.

This is my code:

```kotlin
fun incrementImmediateAchievement(achievementId: String, amount: Int) {
        Log.d(tag, "Incrementing immediate achievement with id $achievementId in an amount of $amount")
        achievementsClient.incrementImmediate(achievementId, amount).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                Log.d(tag, "Achievement $achievementId incremented successfully. Unlocked? ${task.result}")
                ... some code ...
            } else {
                Log.e(tag, "Achievement $achievementId not incremented. Cause: ${task.exception}", task.exception)
                ... some code ...
            }
        }
    }
```

The log in the first branch of the `if` condition is always returning this:

`Achievement [...] incremented successfully. Unlocked? false`

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks for your help!

I have tried following the official docs, expecting to receive a true once the achievement is unlocked, but receiving a false instead.